# Trix editor toolbal error using with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trix

I am trying to implement trix editor with my rails form. So far everything worked fine, but now I created this form:

```
<%= form_for([@statusable, @task.statuses.new], :url => administrator_organization_campaign_task_statuses_path(@organization, @campaign, @task)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.trix_editor :body %>

  <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "bg-transparent animation float-right hover:bg-blue text-blue-dark font-semibold hover:text-white py-2 px-4 border border-blue hover:border-transparent rounded") do %>
    Send
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and my form looks like this:

[image]

I don't know why is trix toolbar showed two time, Also I can type text but toolbar is not working.